# How to remove carriage returns in a text field in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, carriage-return

I have an sqlite database with over 400k records. I have just found that some of the text fields have carriage returns in them and I wanted to clean them out. I wanted to copy the structure of the original table and then do something like:

```
INSERT INTO large_table_copy 
SELECT date, other_fields, replace(dirty_text_field,XXX,"") 
FROM large_table
```

Where `XXX` is whatever the code would be for a carriage return. It's not `\n`. But I can't find out what it is.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

SQLite lets you put line breaks inside string literals, like this:

```
SELECT replace(dirty_text_field, '
', '');
```

If you don't like this syntax, you can pass the string as a `BLOB`: `X'0D'` for `\r` or `X'0A'` for `\n` (assuming the default UTF-8 encoding).

**Edit:** Since this answer was originally written, SQLite has added a `CHAR` function.  So you can now write `CHAR(13)` for `\r` or `CHAR(10)` for `\n`, which will work whether your database is encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: For anyone who's not clear about this... you can do something like `SELECT replace(dirty_text_field, X'0A', '\n')...` to replace single \n chars with equivalent "\n" 2-char strings

Comment: @MarkCarter this is a good answer, so why not post it answer instead of just as a comment?

Comment: @aculich because it does not offer anything fundamentally new provided in the answer

Comment: I don't think this works nowadays. `sqlite> SELECT replace(whitelist.wl_date, CHAR(13), '');` results in `Error: no such column: whitelist.wl_date`. I've tried using database name as a prefix, and omitting the table name.

Answer (score 9):

From @MarkCarter's comment on the question above:

```
SELECT replace(dirty_text_field, X'0A', '\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you operate in a mixed environment with Windows/Linux/Mac it might be a safer solution to do a two step convertion:

```
SELECT replace( replace( dirty_text_field, CHAR(10), "<BR>"), CHAR(13), "") 
FROM temp_config;
```

This will work with most combinations of '`\n`' and '`\r`'